# Resize (Increase/decrease) string length as per the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I have google this and getting many answers, but only for *resize the font size*, what my need is to resize/increase-decrease length of string as per the screen size.

I am creating hybrid application with multiple pages using dynamic text and want to set that text into div for fix length of device and if text length is greater than the height of device create new div as a new page.

```
<!-- for eg. Device Height 480px  -->
<div class="page">
    test text and the
    text that is store
    here with full length
    of the div and device
    is no longer to adjust
</div>
<div class="page"> <!-- This become another page of application -->
    all this string.
</div>

<!-- Device Height 640px -->
<div class="page">
    test text and the
    text that is store
    here with full length
    of the div and device
    is no longer to adjust
    all this string.
</div>
```

Currently, I am working with images as a page into div and set it with full width and auto height into center of screen. But actually, i need to set dynamic text into that div. So I need any suggestion which is helpful to me.

```
<!-- Working - With an image -->
<div class="page">
    <img src="images/page1">
</div>
<div class="page">
    <img src="images/page2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wiewport with typography or anything...

```css
body {
  font-size: 1vw;
}
img {
  width:99vw;
}
```

Link: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: As I have already mentioned that I don't want image or font-size widths, I want to increase decrease string length with most probably javascript

Comment: (Increase/decrease) string length. For e.g. "My name is Kiran". Output: <div class="page">My name is</div><div class="page">Kiran</div> - But only when, "My name is Kiran" is too big to fit into height width of page. Consider my page size is style="width:200px;height:100px;font-size: 26px;"

Comment: Yes, it is !!! still i'll try count total character of paragraph and set as per my requirements.